# Skip sonar plugin execution if maven tests are skipped

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have set up Sonar as maven plugin in my pom, and would like the plugin to run only if tests are run. Use case is I want the sonar plugin to run on my CI server, but not when packaging the jar.
So `mvn test` should execute the sonar plugin, but `mvn -DskipTests clean package` should not.

Today the sonar plugin are running also when I skip the tests.

My setup today:

```
<sonar.host.url>https://sonar.myserver.no</sonar.host.url>
<sonar.login>my token</sonar.login>
<sonar.projectName>My app</sonar.projectName>
.....
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${sonar.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sonar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: add `<configuration><skip>${skipTests}</skip></configuration>` to the `<execution>`-section.

Comment: Thanks, worked as charm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With every plugin, we can add section

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <skip>...</skip>
    ...
</configuration>
```

in an `<execution>`-block to control when the execution should be skipped. In the given case, we can bind the skip logic to the property `skipTests`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${sonar.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sonar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```